# Why does compiler keep asking me to redefine pointer p, q, r in different type?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ListNode {
    int data;
    struct ListNode *next;
};
typedef struct ListNode *NodePtr;

NodePtr p, q, r;
p = (NodePtr)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
q = (NodePtr)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
p->data = 23;
p->link = q;
p->link->data = 45;
q->link = NULL;
r = (NodePtr)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
r->data = 34;
r->link = p->link;
p->link = r;
free(p);
free(q);
free(r);
```

I just want to simply add a  node and change the next pointer and free the pointer.
Please just give me a simple solution to fix.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean? Do you get compiler errors? What message? Please copy exact and complete error messages and warnings as formatted text into your question.

Comment: In C you don't need and should not cast return value of `malloc`. In best case it is useless, in worst case it hides errors.

Comment: Code needs to be inside a function. Is this what you're actually trying to compile or is that different? Consider a [mcve] including exactly the code you're using and the error messages you're receiving.

Comment: How did you get this far without ever realising that you can't have code outside of a function in C?

Comment: OT: using typedefs to hide the star (`*`) from pointer types is a very bad idea. It only creates confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues in the posted code:

- code cannot be executed at the global scope, you must enclose the code in a function definition and call it explicitly directly or indirectly from the `main()` function.
- there is no `link` member in the `ListNode` structure. You probably mean `next` instead.

Also note that it is confusing and error prone to hide pointers behind typedefs.  Pointers are an important part of the C memory model, making them explicit as `struct ListNode *p` or `ListNode *p` improves readability for most programmers.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ListNode {
    int data;
    struct ListNode *next;
};
typedef struct ListNode ListNode;

ListNode *new_node(int data) {
    ListNode *np = malloc(sizeof(*np));
    if (np == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate list node\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    np->data = data;
    np->next = NULL;
    return np;
}

int main(void) {
    ListNode *p = new_node(23);
    ListNode *q = new_node(45);
    ListNode *r = new_node(34);

    r->next = q;
    p->next = r;

    free(p);
    free(q);
    free(r);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p->link=q;
```

from where comes link? Should be next. as they others said write it into a function/main.